# Dynamically changing an object parameter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML (simplified and stripped for purposes of this question):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id="myExp" class="myClass">
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
            <param name="width" value="560" />
            <param name="height" value="310" />
            <param name="id" value="1535" />
        </object>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeId(id)
            {
                // $('#myExp').
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is make the `changeId()` function work. What it should do is replace my `<param name="id" value="1535" />` line above with whatever `id` is passed into the function. How can I use jQuery (or plain old javascript, if need be) to dynamically change the `id` of the `object`/`param` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function changeId(id) {
   $("#myExp param[name=id]").attr('value', id);
}

changeId(6);
```

Remember to actually *call* the function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, this is what you're looking for in jQuery:

```
$("#myExp [name='id']").val(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
function changeId(id) {
    $('#myExp [name=id]').val(id);
}
```