# Changing source and param of object tag inside div

Tags: jquery, html, flash, nodes, attr

I've got the following HTML

```
<div id="flash">
<object type="applicxation/x-shockwave-flash" data="....">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
</div>
```

Now I want to change data attribute of object and also value of wmode param from transparent to not transparent.
And I've got only id of their parent tag div with id flash.
Is that possible ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957179/dynamically-changing-an-object-parameter-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery's  `attr()` function:

```
$('#flash object').attr('data','new atribute value');
$('#flash object param[name="wmode"]').attr('value','not transparent');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, hope this work.

```
$('#flash')
  .find('object')
    .removeAttr('data')
      .attr('data-new_attr','hello')
      .end()
      .find('param')
        .attr('value','not transparent');
```